# Convert json to struct using reflection in golang

Tags: json, reflection, go

```
func deserialize(request *http.Request,typ reflect.Type) (interface{}, *httpNet.HandlerError){

    data,e:=ioutil.ReadAll(request.Body)
    fmt.Println(string(data))
    if e !=nil{
        return nil,&httpNet.HandlerError{e,"could not read request",http.StatusBadRequest}
    }

    v:=typ.Elem()
    payload:=reflect.New(v).Elem().Interface()

    eaa:= json.NewDecoder(request.Body).Decode(payload)

    if e!=nil{
        fmt.Println(eaa.Error())
    }
    fmt.Println(payload)
    fmt.Println(reflect.ValueOf(payload)
        )
    return payload,nil

}
```

to call it:

```
r,_:= deserialize(request,reflect.TypeOf(&testData{}))
```

It does not throw errors and looks completely valid operation to me , but the result is an empty structure of expecting type.

Whats the problem with that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that you are passing a non pointer instance of the type:

```
payload:=reflect.New(v).Elem().Interface()
```

Means "allocate a new pointer to the type, then take the value of it, and extract it as `interface{}`.

You should just keep it at:

```
payload:=reflect.New(v).Interface()
```

BTW It's also redundant that you are passing the type of a pointer, extracting its `Elem()`, then allocating a pointer. Do something like this:

```
if type.Kind() == reflect.Ptr {
   typ = typ.Elem()
}

payload := reflect.New(typ).Interface()
```

then you can pass both pointers and non pointers to the function.

**Edit: Working playground example: http://play.golang.org/p/TPafxcpIU5**

Comment: tanx , tested it but I got the same result

Comment: @Mohsen I'm doing the exact same thing in my code and it works perfectly. Are you sure there's data coming in?

Comment: @Mohsen I've created a simplified working example in the playground. See the answer's edited text.